# Function effect of page with Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Forgive me....
I don't understand one thing

The code

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ShowPage(),
      ),
    );
  },
```

the function is when I click load and move from left to right, while the code

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

back without load page..

How is the code which also allows you to make a page movement from bottom to top or from right to left?

For me it is important because, a page there is a list of guest, click a guest, I delete, and click BACK, the list don't update...